# An unexpected error occurred on a receive. WebRequest already overriden

Tags: c#, .net

I never thought I have to ask a question here, but I am at my wit's end.

We try contact a server and receive XML Data via SOAP from there. Regulary it's running fine, but sometimes and without any hint why, we've got the the following error:

> **Translated from german:**
>   The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a 
>   receive.

So I looked for possible reasons. And I overrode the WebRequest Method.

```
public class MyHttpClientProtocol : SoapHttpClientProtocol
{

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri)
    {
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest) base.GetWebRequest(uri);
        //Setting KeepAlive to false
        webRequest.KeepAlive = false;
        return webRequest;
    }
}
```

First of all? - Is this correct or did I chose the wrong base class? 
I am not sure at all, but I use SoapHttpClientProtocoll in my service, but in the Request Header (used Fiddler) the "Connection" stills "keep-alive".

The error is rare but it occours and if it does, it does it for a longer time.

So I tried to debug the problem. And if I do and I've got the error he repeats to try the delegate:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += delegate { return true; };
```

I can't jump in. VS 2010 does not support it.
I am working with X509Certificate2.

Please give me an idea.. I can't see the solution.

Comment: Without going into the details you have posted, this sounds very like a network error. It doesn't happen often, lasts a bit, and then goes away - that's usually network. Also the text of the message sounds very like a network dropping a connection.

Comment: @simonatrcl Hey; thanks for your response, but really - I can't believe it at all. Why sometimes it should give this network problems. ..

Comment: Networks do have problems. The last corporate I worked at had occasional problems and no-one could say why. The Network Group didn't seem too interested in finding out why, and since I'm not a network expert I'm prepared to believe them when they say, in effect 'Sometimes Sh*t just happens'.